Linguistic term for difficulty in expressing something in a particular language
Example: I need 480 words in an indigenous language to express quantum theory because they haven't integrated it into their thinking. In English, however, I only need one. Or vice versa, in English I have to describe a tree or a house or an instrument or even an abstract thing like a belief concept in long sentences that is self-evident to the native people.
What do you call this linguistically? That is, the difficulty of expressing a certain thing in short words in a specific language?

Is this really a language thing? I'd think it's more cultural—if you talked to an English-speaker a hundred years ago and said "quantum theory" they'd have no idea what you meant and you'd need just as many words to explain it.

Frankly, unless you actually know an indigenous language as a native speaker, your assumption is non-scientific. The meaning of single words in Ameridian languages could give rise to some long number of words in English. Take tuntussuqatarniksaitengqiggtuq (known as a word-sentence) in the Yupik language. And maybe the "minimum amount of a quantity which can exist" (Max Planck) could be rendered much more easily than one might think in one of those languages...
